# How to create a directory "dir" with subdirectories from subdir00 to subdir10 each of which contains subdirectoriess from subsubdir00 to subsubdir10?

Tags: bash, mkdir

So, `dir` contains subirectories from `subdir00` to `subdir10` and each subdirectory contains subirectoriess from `subsubdir00` to `subsubdir10`.

```
mkdir -p dir/subdir0{0..9}/subsubdir0{0..9}
```

works fine, but how to modify it to get correct two digits names? From 0 to 9 the numbers should be as `00` to `09`.

Comment: Is that your homework, or has it some practical use ? We don't do homework for you,

Comment: thank you, it's not my homework) i'm just a dumbass practicing with bash. Could you please help to get result?

Comment: @emanyalpsid What are your OS details? Please [edit] your question to add the output of `uname -a` and `bash --version`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) as follows to do that with a single command:

```
mkdir -p dir/subdir{00..10}/subsubdir{00..10}
```

The `-p` flag is used to create parent directories if needed.

As stated in the Bash documentation I'm referencing above (or in `man bash`):

> Supplied integers may be prefixed with ‘0’ to force each term to have
> the same width. When either x or y begins with a zero, the shell
> attempts to force all generated terms to contain the same number of
> digits, zero-padding where necessary.

Comment: thank you for answer. when doing it- dirs from 0 to 9 doesn't have a "0" before them. I mean instead of 00, 01- there are 0, 1 and so on.

Comment: @emanyalpsid Did you run the command as I provided it? It should work exactly as you want.

Comment: exactly as you provide. but there are no 01, 02, but 1, 2 .. How to change command to force it to make zero's for before 1-9?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog I tested it out, and it workes till 10 is chosen. For example, `echo {00..5}` outputs `00 01 02 03 04 05` while `echo {0..10}` outputs `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`. I guess that's what @emanyalpsid has issues with. Still, you solution is perfectly valid, unless he needs a number higher than `09`

Comment: IIRC the zero-padding feature was added in bash version 4.0 - it's *possible* the OP is using an older version (but if so, that's likely off-topic since no supported version of Ubuntu ships with such an old bash version)

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you! That's probably the issue.

Comment: @steeldriver Indeed zero-padding was introduced in bash version 4.0: https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/CHANGES#L4678-L4680